# Как из одного блока вывести картинку в другой блок? jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Мне нужно из одного блока с классом `.active_img` выводить изображение в другой блок, скажем, с классом `.big_container_img`.

Причем класс `.active_img` добавляется только активному изображению в карусели.

Comment: можно ajax применить и вообще картинка может быть на другой странице , я о load();

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто с помощью JQuery по нажатию на блок

```
$(".active_img").click(function(){
  // просто копируем атрибут href из одного блока в другой
  $(".big_container img").attr("href",$(".active_img img").attr("href")); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто скопировать изображение как html тег:

```
$('.big_container_img').append($('.active_img img'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Например (как один из вариантов):

```js
$('.slide__link').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Slide show prew On click! \n');

  var $this = $(this),
      item = $this.closest('.slide__item'),
      wrap = $this.closest('.slideShow'),
      gap = wrap.find('.big_container_img '),
      itemPath = $this.find('img').attr('src'),
      dur = 500;

  if(!item.hasClass('active_img')){
    item.addClass('.active_img').siblings().removeClass('active_img');
    gap.find('img').fadeOut(dur, function(){
      $(this).attr('src', itemPath).fadeIn(dur);
    });
  }   

});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.slide__item {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

  
<div class="slideShow">    
  <div class="big_container_img ">
    <img src="http://vedmochka.net/media/k2/categories/250.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <ul class="slide__list flex-row">
    <li class="slide__item">
      <a href="#" class="slide__link">
        <img src="http://vedmochka.net/media/k2/items/cache/c1e21b05a381c806381286f711913568_M.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="slide__item">
      <a href="#" class="slide__link">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Juletr%C3%A6et.jpg/250px-Juletr%C3%A6et.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```